# String[] array taking items out individually

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a method that requires a String[] for some details but after putting these details in how do I get them out one by one?

```
new String[] otherDetails = {"100", "100", "This is a picture"};
```

now in the picture I want to set the first string as the height, the second as the width, and the third as a description.

Comment: Do we really need three identical answers?

Comment: @Steve Absolutely not. But it seems to happen frequently on the really easy questions.

Answer (score 3):

You refer to an element of an array by its index, like this:

```
height = otherDetails[0]; // 100
width = otherDetails[1]; // 100
description = otherDetails[2]; // This is a picture
```

Comment: It's also worth nothing that Array indices start at 0 and go to Array.size - 1, which is the standard in at least every programming language I've ever worked with.

Answer (score 2):

You use the index to get the values

```
height = otherDetails[0];
width = otherDetails[1];
description = otherDetails[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract The details from array as follows :

```
height = otherDetails[0]; // 100
 width = otherDetails[1]; // 100
 description = otherDetails[2]; // This is a picture
```

Then call your method `MyFunction(String heigth,String width,String description);`

Comment: Why are you posting an identical answer to the other two?

Answer (score 0):

The index comments are probably what you're looking for, but you can also iterate through the elements using a loop.

```
int arraySize = stringArray.length;
for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
    if(i==0)
        height = stringArray[i];  //do stuff with that index
}
```

This isn't the "right" approach for your particular problem, but I think it might help you understand ways that you can access items inside an array.

Side note, you could use alternative syntax:

```
String[] array = new String[3];
//fill in array
for(String s : array){
    //this cycles through each element which is available as "s"
}
```